# Flask execute libreoffice --convert-to command on ubuntu

Tags: python, libreoffice

I have a shell script that runs the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

libreoffice --convert-to pdf "$1.docx"
```

When I execute it in terminal, it works and the PDF file is created. However, when I try to run it by my Flask app with the following code, the PDF file is not created.

```
doc_base.save('FILE_TO_BE_CONVERTED.docx')    
subprocess.run(['./to_pdf.sh', 'FILE_TO_BE_CONVERTED'])
```

I know the .sh script is being executed by my App, but it just does not generate the PDF file and no error occurs.

Comment: You might want to call `subprocess.run` with the `check` argument, so that you can check whether libreoffice is returning a nonzero error code. As is no error will be thrown. Example: `subprocess.run(['./to_pdf.sh', 'FILE_TO_BE_CONVERTED'], check=True)`

Comment: @R.Davidson `check=True` shows that my process returned a non-zero exit status 127. And now I can see in the terminal the message `func=xmlSecCheckVersionExt:file=xmlsec.c:line=188:obj=unknown:subj=unknown:error=19:invalid version:mode=abi compatible;expected minor version=2;real minor version=2;expected subminor version=25;real subminor version=26`. Despite that, running in terminal it still converts the file to PDF.